# How to change the position of jquery dialog box into center?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a jquery dialog box where I am showing the content of a DIV. But the problem is the dialog box is appearing at the bottom of the page whenever the link button is clicked as the link button also at the bottom of the page but I want this to appear at the top of the page so that user don't have to scroll down to find the dialog box.

Here is my aspx code:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="OpenDialog('#divNominees','Add Nominee')">
```

Jquery code:

```
   function OpenDialog(obj,title) {
    $(obj).dialog({ title: title, modal: true })
    $(obj).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
    var p = $(obj).parent();
  }
```

I would appreciate most if someone help me out of this because I already wasted a whole morning for solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep your div not nested with your other tables/divs or whatever. In the below sample, tblOuter is the id of a table where I wanted the dialog box to be centered.

```
 $("#divNominees'").dialog({
             modal: true,
             position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: $("#tblOuter") },
             title: "Nominees",
             dialogClass: "ui-dialog-content"
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
once try with add css 
margin:0 auto; 

or only auto.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)

```
$('my-selector').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
```